# Function name must be a string php?

Tags: php, scope

After few hours of googling and searching for answer, i gave up and got very frustrated with php, no support out there on basic errors. Anyway, here is my function, what am I doing wrong?

```
$accessToken = function(){
        $array = array(
            "foo" => "bar",
            "bar" => "foo"
        );
        
        $obj = json_encode($array);
        $obj = json_decode($obj);
        
        return $obj->foo;
};

$getInfo = function(){
       
        $code = $accessToken();
        return $code;

        
};

$getInfo();
```

I get error

> Notice: Undefined variable: accessToken in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\lab\cfhttp.php on line 43
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\lab\cfhttp.php on line 43

Comment: just name them `function accessToken(){}` and `function getInfo(){}` and use them in the same way `accessToken()` and `getInfo()`

Comment: $accessToken isnt in scope inside $getInfo()

Comment: _"no support out there on basic errors"_ - There are literally thousands of sites/tutorials (including this site) explaining almost every possible error message in PHP and how it works. Regarding this  issue, I recommend reading about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I agree, there is allot, but i googled and couldn't find anything that will help me to fix this error. It's easy when you master this language, and in my case it took me 2 hours of googling and is there was nothing what superDJ mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$accessToken` isnt in scope inside `$getInfo()`

```
$accessToken = function(){
        $array = array(
            "foo" => "bar",
            "bar" => "foo"
        );

        $obj = json_encode($array);
        $obj = json_decode($obj);

        return $obj->foo;
};

$getInfo = function($accessTokenFunction){

        $code = $accessTokenFunction();
        return $code;


};

$getInfo($accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

`use ()` to take a variable inside this scope

```
$getInfo = function() use ($accessToken) {
    $code = $accessToken();
    return $code;
};
```

https://3v4l.org/BOtnf

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you usually define a function in another fashion. Try the following:

```
function accessToken() {
     $array = array(
          "foo" => "bar",
          "bar" => "foo"
     );

     $obj = json_encode($array);
     $obj = json_decode($obj);

     return $obj->foo;
}

function getInfo() {
     $code = accessToken();
     return $code;
}

getInfo();
```

You can also take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php